# Can't Style Blazor Components

Tags: c#, css, blazor

i simply don't know how to style Blazor components, i started a project that comes with something already done, like a counter page, a navbar and the kind of things.
There's a file in the `wwwroot` folder `App.css`, there's a lot of style written there but when a delete the code, nothing happens, the page continues beautiful, when i insert some code, wet nothing happens, so how do i style this pages? Where should i put my css files in order to style them?

[Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCpfD.png)

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the solution (ctrl + shift + b) and then refresh the web page?

Comment: MyComponent' does not have a property matching the name 'style' - looks like Blazor can't handle style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the CSS is being cached.

Is is included in the "index.html" file. Understand that most of the styling actually comes from the bootstrap.min.css file.

You could try changing the reference to

```
<link href="css/app.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet" />
```

See if that makes any difference.

Comment: The problem really was cache, for some reason even when i reloaded the app with CTRL + F5, the cache remained. I feel so stupid haha.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lukys - you also haved to Save that .css file between edits. Make sure it's on disk.

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply the styling you need to load the resources to the corresponding page as following:

```
<StyleSheet Resource="folder/MyStyles.css" Assembly="GetType().Assembly"></StyleSheet>
```

More information about this can be found in the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-blazor-bindings/ui/css-styles

Comment: At least this is the solution that I would try. Never used blazer, but the documentation mentions this

Comment: Didn't worked :(
It gave me a message "Found markup element with unexpected name 'StyleSheet'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace."
And if i put the @, other error displays.
What a pain in my ***.

Comment: hmm, that is weird. Are you using the Blazor server or the new Blazor Client? @Lukys

Answer (score 0):

For Your CSS, makes sure this is in your _Host.cshtml file

```
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This line works if you have a CSS file under wwwroot/CSS/site.css, which is the default for a new blazor project.

[image]

If you have a difference CSS file, you can drag it from Solution Explorer to the _Host.cshtml file and Visual Studio adds the link for you.

Not that you need to know this, but you can also reference CSS in a Nuget package like this:

```
<link href="~/_content/DataJuggler.Blazor.Components/css/circle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I use BlazorStyled a lot because you can dynamically change CSS values:

I have an open source project that uses BlazorStyled Nuget package.

Code is here if you want a working example:

https://github.com/DataJuggler/BlazorChat

An example of using BlazorStyled

```
<Styled @bind-Classname="@BubbleStyle">
    background-image: url('@ImageUrl');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0vh;
    width: 84%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 1.2vh;
</Styled>
```

In the above example, @BubbleStyle is just a string property on my component.

The @ImageUrl property changes for each chat message, where I show one of these bubbles:

[image]

Site is also live, but not many people have signed up yet:

https://blazorchat.com